# Index of out of bounds while assigning property .?

Tags: java, jstl, taglib

I have below FieldValue modal class, with textValues property of ArrayList of String.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_STD_FIELD_VALUE")
public class FieldValue implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "FLD_VERSION")
private int version;

@Column(name = "FLD_VALUE")
private ArrayList<String> textValues;

  public ArrayList<String> getTextValues() {
    if(this.textValues == null){
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
   return textValues;
  }
}
```

and Below is addForm.jsp . I am assigning that textValues list to input fields as shown in below code.

```
<form:form name="moduleForm" modelAttribute="fieldValue"  id="moduleForm"   action="/module/saveAddForm.htm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateMandetoryFields();">
    <table width="100%" id="preferenceTable" style="border: 0px solid #ccc;">
        <c:forEach items="${fields}" var="field" varStatus="no">
            <tr height="30px"  bordercolor="#FFF" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Module Name">
                <td width="60%" align="left">
                    <form:input type="${field.type}" style="width: 250px;" path="textValues[${no.index}]"   title="Name of the Module" />  
                </td>
         </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

Belos is code from controller, I am using MultiActionController.

```
public ModelAndView addForm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    String moduleId = request.getParameter("moduleId");

    Module module = moduleDao.get(Module.class,Long.parseLong(moduleId));
    List<Fields> fields = fieldDao.getAllFields(Long.parseLong(moduleId));

    ModelAndView model = new  ModelAndView("admin/module/addForm");
    model.addObject("fields",fields);
    model.addObject("fieldValue",fieldValue);

    return model;
}
```

It is giving me below error message.

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'textValues[0]' of bean class [com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.model.module.FieldValue]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'textValues[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Please guide me to resolve this issues.

Comment: You have put `private ArrayListList<String>` in your code. Try `ArrayList<String>`. Or did you have a typo in the code snippet?

Comment: in your controller, can we see the part where you initialize the `fieldValue`?

Comment: FieldValue fieldValue = new FieldValue(); this line is there in controller.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${!empty fieldValue.textValues && no.index < fn:length(fieldValue.textValues)}">
        <form:input type="${field.type}" 
            style="width: 250px;" 
            path="${fieldValue.textValues[${no.index}]}"   
            title="Name of the Module" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- for index that is beyond the length of fieldValue.textValues -->
        <form:input type="${field.type}" 
            style="width: 250px;" 
            path=""   
            title="Name of the Module" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

**Note**

- the code above assumes that `fieldValue` is not `null` and `fieldValue.textValues` is not empty
- the code has a condition to check if the **index** (denoted by variable `no`) of the current loop is still **within** the bounds of the `ArrayList` `fieldValue.textValues`.
- the code above also assumes that you have already imported `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
  prefix="fn" %>` to your `jsp`.

Comment: ${fields} is another list object. I am iterating it and in every iteration, creating one input filed. I want to bind that input fields with filedValue arraylist.

Comment: @RBP `${fields}` is a list of what? `FieldValue` objects?

Comment: ${fields} is list of Fields Objects not FieldValue.

Comment: I added same logic.I am getting FieldValue as null.can you guide me about how it is coming null?